# Makerbase MKS Slot2 V1.0 + RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD + RAMPS 1.4

Tags: diy-3d-printer, ramps-1.4, reprap, full-graphic-smart-controller

I want to add an **external SD card adapter** on my **RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD**. My 3D printer is based on (Arduino Mega + RAMPS v1.4 + RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD). 
I buy an SD Card Adapter from Aliexpress  (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32873382195.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4f544c4d5UzB1L) and now I want to add this adapter on my RAMPS 1.4 while not disturbing the working of RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD. 
Please guide me how can I add this to my RAMPS? Thanks!

**My 3D Printer Details:**

- Model: A Standard DIY Prusa 3D Printer (Cartesian)
- Firmware: Repetier Firmware

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD already has an SD card slot reader at the back of the board:

[image: RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD backside]

Basically one of the 10 pin headers is used for the display and rotary encoder and reset, the other header is used by the SD card reader.

The module referenced in the question is a breakout SD card slot reader for the TFT (touchscreen) display controllers. Whether these are compatible with the EXP2 header of the RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD should be compared with the schematics. The schematics of the RepRapDiscount Full Graphics LCD are available, but for the SD slot breakout cannot be found. It is therefore unsure if the EXP2 is fully compatible for the SD slot board. To use the EXP2 on a RAMPS shield, you need the L-shaped connector.

The description of the Slot2 explicitly says that it is meant to be connected to either a TFT35 or a TFT70 MKS touchscreen display. In order to use it directly to your RAMPS shield requires finding out which pin goes where.